# Event Consumers in Event Sourcing and duplicate code

Tags: events, architecture, microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am pretty new to event sourcing, and we have a domain which we consider applying Event Sourcing on.

We have an app which will be storing domain events to an `Oracle DB` and the consumers of the events which would use them to generate read models (all read models will be generated in memory), those consumers will mostly use a poll model to fetch the events.

Which means that they will get a request and based on that request they will consume a stream of events and generate their read model then return it to the caller.

So for example

`Event Generation API` --> Generates events for aggregates of type A and stores them in an Oracle DB.

`Consumer 1` --> gets a request for a certain type A aggregate, then it fetches the events and replays them to prepare it's read model.

`Consumer 2` --> does exactly the same thing but presents a different read model

**Why are we using ES**

1. We need to provide historical representations of data with each change and the state of the aggregate at that change.
2. We need to be able to get a snapshot of an aggregate at any point in time per event basis, for example, when changing a name, then we need the state of the aggregate at that name changed event time
3. We need to represent the diff of the state of the aggregate between points in time

But all those requirements need to be done in a poll manner, which means the consumers will request the view at a certain point in time (could be the latest or a previous one)

**Question 1**

Since both `consumer 1` and `consumer 2` are going to execute basically the same logic to replay the events, then where should the code for replaying the events be? Will we implement a common library code? Does this mean that we will have duplicate replay code across consumers?

I am worried that when we update an event schema we need to update multiple consumers

**Question 2**

Is this a good case of event sourcing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which means that they will get a request and based on that request they will consume a stream of events and generate their read model then return it to the caller.

This is a strange type of Read model, at least for me. It does not seem very fast and speed is one of the Read model's strength.

In general, Read models process events in the background, as early as possible (i.e. milliseconds after they are emitted); the results are persisted in a fast database (on disk or memory), with all the indexes applied so when the request comes the response is fast.

> 1. We need to provide historical representations of data with each change and the state of the aggregate at that change.
> 2. We need to be able to get a snapshot of an aggregate at any point in time per event basis, for example, changing a name, then we need the state at that name changed event

The state of the Aggregate should be hidden, private - the Aggregate needs a high level of encapsulation. Maybe you need an interpretation of the Events generated up until that point: this is a Read model's responsibility. The state is used **only** by the Aggregate to decide if and what events it will generate on the next command.

So, I suggest that you design a Read model that does exactly that: it maintains another state for each Aggregate, in a flat (non-event-sourced) persistence.

> 3. We need to represent the diff of the state of the aggregate between points in time

Again, this should be done by a Read model.

> Since both consumer 1 and consumer 2 are going to execute basically the same logic to replay the events, then where should the code for replaying the events be? Will we implement a common library code? Does this mean that we will have duplicate replay code across consumers?

But then you said: `Consumer 2 --> does exactly the same thing but presents a different read model`. This means they don't basically do the same thing. If you are referring to the code that fetches the events from the Event store and feeds the Consumers, then yes, you can put that in a common library.

> I am worried that we when update our event schema we need to update multiple consumers

This is a *problem* but one that has [multiple solutions](https://leanpub.com/esversioning/read).

> Is this a good case of event sourcing?

It seems that YES, it *may* be a case of event sourcing.

Comment: Well, the thing is we cannot really generate the read model until we get a request for it because they can be random and they can request data at any point in time.
Can you elaborate more about "The state of the Aggregate should be hidden, private - the Aggregate needs a high level of encapsulation." the state that I meant was the domain state or how our data looked at that point in time, which the consumer is going to present to it's requesting caller

Comment: I would also like to mention that we are keeping a snapshot of the data in a traditional RDBMS table schema regularly, those event consumer provide different representation of the data which involves historical events

Comment: @engma In CQRS, by definition, the Aggregate (the Write/Command model) **must not** be queried. You (the client code, the Application services etc) cannot know what's inside an Aggregate, it's state is private to it. For that you have the Read models; you build them in order to construct another state that is fitted for querying needs. There is the case where the read state looks a lot like the write/Aggregate's state: it does not matter, they must be stored different, in different persistence.

Comment: Yes, so my event consumers will only fetch the events and use them to build the representation they need or the Read Model they need of the data.
The main difference is that we use a poll model, so the event stream will not have subscribers, they will be more like consumers (at least for now we don't have pub/sub plans)

Comment: @engma Yes. The method of receiving events doesn't matter, it is the same in pub/sub. Polling gives better resilience but that's another topic. You could built the read model when the request comes, it is *permitted*, but it is not fast.

Comment: thanks a lot, I got it now :). Thankfully for now our events per entity will not so many so replaying them would be trivial, although of course, we are considering a caching mechanism